# How to save an object with objects in local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have a class Videoclub, the main atributes are (that class already has getters and setters) :

```
var nombre = nom;
var clientes = new Array();
var productos = new Array();
```

I'm trying to create a array of objects Videoclub

```
let videoclubs = new Array();
let videoclub = new Videoclub("videoshop"); // videoshop is the atribute nombre
videoclubs.push(videoclub);
```

I tried to save the array in local storage

```
localStorage.setItem(nombreEnStorage, JSON.stringify(videoclubs));
```

and when I pick up from local storage

```
function cargar(nombreEnStorage) {
    let texto = localStorage.getItem(nombreEnStorage);
    return JSON.parse(texto);
}
```

I can't access any methods of videoclub, not even getters and setters.

Console says:

> Uncaught TypeError: videoclubs[0].getNombre is not a function

Comment: Functions are not valid JSON, therefore cannot be stringified.

Comment: So you need to map the array and return `new Videoclub()` for each item

Comment: Beyond not being able to represent functions, JSON doesn't know how to represent `Videoclub` but it does know how to represent a regular Object, so `JSON.stringify` will convert a constructed object into a regular object and lose any inheritance information. You will need to add an extra layer to re-construct

Comment: And, how i can add this extra layer to re-construct ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have here a working Example

```
 let persons = new Array();
let obj1 = {name: "John Doe", age: 30, car: {color: "red", model: "Honda"}};

persons.push(obj1);
localStorage.setItem("persons", JSON.stringify(persons));
function cargar(nombreEnStorage) {
    let texto = localStorage.getItem(nombreEnStorage);
    return JSON.parse(texto);
}
cargar("persons");
let personsFromLocalStorage = cargar("persons");
console.log(personsFromLocalStorage);
```

if you want to convert back again to class Object to access functions do the following:

```
Object.cast = function cast(rawObj, constructor)
{
    var obj = new constructor();
    for(var i in rawObj)
        obj[i] = rawObj[i];
    return obj;
}
var fooJSON = Object.cast(persons, Object)[0];
console.log(fooJSON);
```

Comment: Provide how this doesn't solve the question: How to save an object with objects in local storage? The internal structure of your classes or how to access your methods its irrelevant to localStorage

Comment: I dont´t understand the reason for obj[i] = rawObj[i]; can you explain it?